# Regex Syntax For detecting any character inside bracket

Tags: regex

this is my string

> [cmd][lPrt][brd][0][{\"points\":[\"326, 191\",\"327, 191\",\"328, 189\",\"328, 176\",\"328, 150\",\"328, 124\",\"316, 93\",\"287, 79\",\"199, 76\",\"154, 82\",\"130, 112\",\"121, 195\",\"121, 226\",\"135, 264\",\"164, 292\",\"184, 296\",\"272, 301\",\"392, 276\",\"462, 243\",\"512, 183\",\"513, 159\",\"507, 141\",\"504, 138\",\"495, 135\",\"485, 134\",\"480, 134\",\"470, 146\",\"464, 158\",\"458, 174\",\"458, 187\",\"464, 217\",\"484, 245\",\"524, 302\",\"556, 345\",\"579, 403\",\"586, 439\",\"586, 450\",\"571, 459\",\"500, 459\",\"373, 411\",\"312, 383\",\"262, 362\",\"260, 361\",\"260, 361\"],\"DrawingType\":0,\"PenColor\":\"Black\",\"PenSize\":5.0}]

i want to search anything inside brackets

this must be the result:

[cmd]
[lPrt]
[brd]
[0]
[{\"points\":[\"326, 191\",\"327, 191\",\"328, 189\",\"328, 176\",\"328, 150\",\"328, 124\",\"316, 93\",\"287, 79\",\"199, 76\",\"154, 82\",\"130, 112\",\"121, 195\",\"121, 226\",\"135, 264\",\"164, 292\",\"184, 296\",\"272, 301\",\"392, 276\",\"462, 243\",\"512, 183\",\"513, 159\",\"507, 141\",\"504, 138\",\"495, 135\",\"485, 134\",\"480, 134\",\"470, 146\",\"464, 158\",\"458, 174\",\"458, 187\",\"464, 217\",\"484, 245\",\"524, 302\",\"556, 345\",\"579, 403\",\"586, 439\",\"586, 450\",\"571, 459\",\"500, 459\",\"373, 411\",\"312, 383\",\"262, 362\",\"260, 361\",\"260, 361\"],\"DrawingType\":0,\"PenColor\":\"Black\",\"PenSize\":5.0}]

i tried to do it myself using this regex param :

string param = @"[[][\w\s\d-{}']*]";

but it will not detect the last long text inside the bracket.. any help please..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input has nested brackets - your language isn't regular, so you can't do what you want with regular expressions.  If you want a parser, you should write a parser.

If you're guaranteed the nesting will only be one level deep, you can probably come up with an expression to handle it.

Edit - if your actual input doesn't have nesting (in conflict with your question, but in line with what you said in the comments below), this regular expression should be fine:

```
\[.*?\]
```

With exactly 0 or 1 levels of nesting:

```
\[([^[\]]|\[[^[\]]*\])*\]
```

Adapted from the example at this [link](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-recursion).

Comment: the string is only 1 line and no other [] inside the brackets.. so my format is like this.. [anycharacters][anycharacters][anycharacters][anycharacters][anycharacters] and detect only the anycharacters

Comment: @vrynxzent - that's not what your input has.  It has [somestuff [morestuff] evenmorestuff].

Comment: yep yep.. so how can i detect that somestuff. morestuff, evenmorestuff inside the brackets? 1 level deep only

Comment: Edited with an answer for a single layer of nesting.

Answer (score 1):

This worked in a quick test:

```
(?: [[]{ .*? }] | [[] .*? ] )
```

I like to leave white space in for readability; you'll want to take it out, or specify the "IgnorePatternWhitespace" option.

There are two alternatives to match on: "[{....}]" or "[...]". It might be a little lazy, but something you can perhaps build upon.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is an array index filled with json.

This is the array index:
`[cmd][lPrt][brd][0]`

The rest is all json. So now, depending on what language you're using, you can decode the json data and get the result you're looking for.

I used PHP and used `json_decode` to decode the json part and it displays like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [points] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 326, 191
                    [1] => 327, 191
                    [2] => 328, 189
                    [3] => 328, 176
                    [4] => 328, 150
                    [5] => 328, 124
                    [6] => 316, 93
                    [7] => 287, 79
                    [8] => 199, 76
                    [9] => 154, 82
                    [10] => 130, 112
                    [11] => 121, 195
                    [12] => 121, 226
                    [13] => 135, 264
                    [14] => 164, 292
                    [15] => 184, 296
                    [16] => 272, 301
                    [17] => 392, 276
                    [18] => 462, 243
                    [19] => 512, 183
                    [20] => 513, 159
                    [21] => 507, 141
                    [22] => 504, 138
                    [23] => 495, 135
                    [24] => 485, 134
                    [25] => 480, 134
                    [26] => 470, 146
                    [27] => 464, 158
                    [28] => 458, 174
                    [29] => 458, 187
                    [30] => 464, 217
                    [31] => 484, 245
                    [32] => 524, 302
                    [33] => 556, 345
                    [34] => 579, 403
                    [35] => 586, 439
                    [36] => 586, 450
                    [37] => 571, 459
                    [38] => 500, 459
                    [39] => 373, 411
                    [40] => 312, 383
                    [41] => 262, 362
                    [42] => 260, 361
                    [43] => 260, 361
                )

            [DrawingType] => 0
            [PenColor] => Black
            [PenSize] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: yep.. im using json.. i just want to get the anycharacters inside bracket. :) including that json part..